# Having error from a single line. What did I do wrong?

Tags: java, substring, variable-length

Here's my code:

```
while(n4.hasNext()){
            sLine = n4.next();
            if(sLine.contains("*")){
                F1 = sLine.indexOf("*");
                L1 = sLine.indexOf("*", F1+1);
                upperC = sLine.substring(F1+1, L1-1);
                upperC = upperC.toUpperCase();
//              sLine = sLine.substring(0,F1-1)+upperC+sLine.substring(L1+1, sLine.length() - 1);
            }
```

On the last line where it starts with "sLine", for some reason, I can't seem to get it to reach the end of the line without it saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at assign3.LoopPatterns.emphasize(LoopPatterns.java:138)
    at assign3.LoopPatterns.main(LoopPatterns.java:291)
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  What's the minor error?

---

UPDATE

The line of the string being passed is "To you the *   victor   * of all!"

What's being edited is   *  victor  *  to VICTOR and placed back into the string sLine.

I'm trying to take from an assigned scanner from main method and then taking what I get I from the scanner and upper casing a specifically designated selection between two asterisks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the while loop? Maybe we can help you restructure your code to simplify that line

Comment: You are attempting to access an out of bounds region of the string.  Show us the value of `sLine` for which this is happening.

Comment: updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

If the line begins with a *, F1 will be 0. 
So F1-1 will be a problem here:

```
Line = sLine.substring(0,F1-1)
```

Comment: I'm trying to take *  victor  *  and make it say VICTOR without the asterisks.

Comment: Print sLine, F1,and L1 in the loop and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: This will ONLY work if you have two asterisks on your String. (But this should give you an idea.)

```
String givenString = "To you the * victor * of all!";

// + 1, because the beginning index is inclusive for of String#substring
String betweenTheAsterisk = givenString.substring(givenString.indexOf("*") + 1 , givenString.lastIndexOf("*")).toUpperCase().trim();
System.out.println(betweenTheAsterisk);

// this is a REGEX that basically captures everything between the asterisk, inclusive
String finalString = givenString.replaceAll("\\*(.*?)\\*", betweenTheAsterisk);
System.out.println(finalString);
```

The output:

```
VICTOR
To you the VICTOR of all!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(scan.hasNext()){
        sLine = scan.nextLine();
        if(sLine.contains("*")){
            int F1 = sLine.indexOf("*");
            int L1 = sLine.indexOf("*", F1+1);
            String lowerC = sLine.substring(F1+1, L1-1);
            upperC = lowerC.toUpperCase().trim();                
            sLine = sLine.replaceAll("\\*\\s*"+lowerC +"\\s*\\*", upperC);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to debug, you can find the problem easily:
Print out the values of `F1` and `L1` and find out the problem.

It might be because of your while loop, when the input is `"To you the * victor * of all!"`, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("[\s|\p{P}]?\*[^\s](.*?)[^\s]\*[\s|\p{P}]?")
    '[\s|\p{P}]?\*[^\s] = optional blank space or punctuation followed by '*', followed by anything but blank
    '(.*?) = anything inside both '*'
    '[^\s]\*[\s|\p{P}]? = anything but blank, followed by '*', followed by optional blank space or punctuation
    ' something like this = " *This is a bold text*! This isn't."
```

This is a Regex I made in VB some months ago, will detect any appearances between **, but only when they are right before/after the text.

```
*Hi there!* -> This is bolded out

*Hi, my * is quite big*! ->The full sentence will be bolded here. (Ya, couldn't think of a better example)
```

Maybe it helps and you can use it. AFAIR, this worked for any number * in the text